# How to fix this A-frame Angular issue with showing OBJ

Tags: javascript, html, angular, aframe, webvr

im adding an already made up A-frame scene VR musueum to my actual project but the resources are not loading

changing the src of the assets

```
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/lzma.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/ctm.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/CTMLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/aframe-teleport-controls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/spheres_anim.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/anim_1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/anim_2.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/mocap.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/envMapMaterial.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/ctm_component.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/VR/js/mobile_component.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

and exemple of the obj


<a-asset-item id="good_samaritan-obj" src="../../assets/VR/models/good_samaritan.obj"></a-asset-item>
    <img id="good_samaritan-texture" src="../../assets/VR/textures/good_samaritan.jpg">
    <!-- - good_samaritan -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for loading a model looks incorrect. Please refer to the guide and docs: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/models.html or post a Glitch with full code sample.

```
<a-entity obj-model="obj: myobj.obj; mtl: mymtl.mtl">
```

Comment: Hello, i tried the same code in localhost just html qnd css no angular and its working no prob but i need it inside angular